# Only show box-shadow on part of a side

Tags: html, css

So I have a header that is shown in the snippet below.

My problem is I only want the shadow around the `a` tag to show on the part that has expanded out of its container `div`, to create the impression that the white edge is all one element.

Basically I only want the shadow on the left and on the right to go from the bottom of the `a` element to the bottom of the `div`. While also showing on the bottom of the `a` element.

Screenshot of what I'm after in case my descriptive capabilities are not functioning:

[image]

I've tried playing with `z-index` but haven't been able to get it to work.

My thought with `z-index` was to push the `a` behind the `div`, then pull the `img` in front of all.

I would prefer a CSS-only solution, as I don't want to have to modify the html, but if I have to I have to.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: @LokeshGupta as I've just added in my question: *Basically I only want the shadow on the left and on the right to go from the bottom of the `a` element to the bottom of the `div`. While also showing on the bottom of the `a` element.*

Comment: Check answer may be it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is `box-shadow` syntax,

```
box-shadow: offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color
```

Try reducing it's `spread-radius` and increase it shadow towards `y-axis`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with more details of what I'm looking for

Comment: @CalvT븃 Yes you could do that even using pseudo selector a:before

Comment: @CalvT븃 Check this jsFiddle, you can add multiple box-shadows effects and using z-index align that psudo-selector to bottom of div. https://jsfiddle.net/ehfnygwz/1/

Comment: That's great thanks. I've put my final solution here https://jsfiddle.net/ehfnygwz/3/ - care to update your answer? I'll accept then.

Comment: Welcome @CalvT븃 :-), much similar to first jsFiddle. Till if needed you can add multiple box-shadow effects, done that.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:-

Using jquery you can compute the css for span dynamically. [Check this.](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/p0roLqem/1/)

Html modified, added a `<span>` below anchor tag and added shadow to the span

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;*/
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
}

.shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top:50px;
  height: 10px;
  width:120px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  z-index:0;
  position:absolute;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  </a>
  <span class="shadow">r
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway the span can calculate it's sizing automatically?

Comment: Javascript solutions are there, is that ok ?

Comment: Yup, any extra html will have to be injected via jQuery anyway

Comment: so the `span` will be injected by jquery ??

Comment: Yes it will be. I'm editing an existing site, and can't change the html, hence the CSS only preference

Comment: frnt has given me a CSS only solution which fits my purposes better, but thanks for your example, and have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by css `pseudo` element.

Just add css part

```
a:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 5px -5px #000000;
}
a:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow:-5px 5px 5px -5px #000000;
}
```

```css
   * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  position:relative;
  /* box-shadow:0px 5px 5px -5px #000000; */
}
a:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 5px -5px #000000;
}
a:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow:-5px 5px 5px -5px #000000;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  </a>
</div>
```